# Trigger an action through button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This should be an easy question, but I just can't figure it out. I want to trigger an action (which just renders a page) through a button using "button_to" in view:

```
<%= button_to "Fresh", action: 'fresh', method: 'get' %>
```

The error says "No route matches [POST] "/static_pages/fresh"". It seems that the button still uses "post" instead the "get". Meanwhile, if I use "link_to", it works fine.

```
<%= link_to "Fresh", action: 'fresh', method: 'get' %>
```

Thanks for any comments and help.

Comment: what controller is the `fresh` action on? Can you show your routes.rb file?

Comment: "Fresh" is in the "static_pages controller". In my point of view, "button_to" is similar to "link_to", which works fine in the same view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= button_to "delete", {:controller => :static_pages, :action => 'fresh'}, :method => :get %>
```

Also check your routes.rb to ensure that the route to fresh is defined.

Comment: It works. Why does "link_to" doesn't need to specify the controller while "button_to" needs? Weird.

Comment: Actually, I am almost positive that button_to doesn't need the controller either. I don't believe you should have any problems deleting that part if you wish. The real problem with your initial code wasn't that; rather it was due to brackets not being there.